# How to implement Ad Hoc on Radio Frequency node?

Tags: rf, wireless, networking

i want to implement RF based network as indicated in below figure 
[image]

Node is Basically Radio Frequency Transceiver i.e Si4432 interfaced with C8051 Micro controller . These nodes are simply Act as a Transceiver's .

Simple Concept behind the Project is that data packet from Tx node is transmitted to reach Rx node but due to the more distance repeater's added between Tx and Rx node .

So if i want to increase distance then i have to add repeater node 
into the network and i want to add this node using **add hoc**   concept
so i want some valuable suggestion , study material regarding this , 
and do i need to implement routing protocol for this ?

and sorry for my poor English    !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple protocol you can implement will consist of following things

1. Dedicated Transmitter-Receiver pairs: 
   Things will get simple if you assign specific responsibility to each node. This responsibility is to take data from the previous node and ensuring its successful delivery to the next node. (and thus obviously discarding any other data from any other node)
2. Use of acknowledgment(ACK) to ensure successful delivery of the data:
   If a transmitter(let's say rep 2) sends data to its intended receiver (rep 3 in case of rep 2 as transmitter), then the receiver (rep 3) should send an ACK signal back to the transmitter(rep 2) to let it (rep 2) know that the data has been received correctly. Thus transmitter node (rep 2) will not reattempt retransmission.
3. Avoiding resending the data which has already been passed to the next node:
   Assigning sequence number (or packet number) to each newly generated data packet will help to discard any previous data which has already been taken care of.
4. Structuring the protocol/algorithm in such a way that the nodes cause minimum interference to each other:
   you can implement schemes such as slotted ALOHA, random backoff, CSMA-CA. Although some of these might not be very necessary depending on your scenario (e.g. If your wireless network is expected to carry huge data, then you will have to take care of proper scheduling of the data and avoid collisions. In that case above schemes will be very helpful).

Also, understand that there is always a trade-off between data rate and range you can get. If your wireless link between end nodes (Tx node and Rx node) is expected to carry only small amount of data, then you can operate at lower data rate which will result in high sensitivity improvement and thus range improvement, in that case repeater nodes might not be necessary. Si4432 is 900 MHz transceiver and these RF frequencies have quite high penetration in the air, in the order of few kilometers depending on how you design your wireless link (keeping low data rate, using directional antennas, proper modulation protocol etc).

Comment: Thanks you Ashutosh Sir for your  valuable suggestion          
 many doubts in my  mind now got cleared....but one ques is still remain how can i dynamically add repeater node into network ?

Comment: In the previous case, each transmitter node had its intended receiver and each receiver node had its predefined transmitter node from which it was allowed to accept data and forward it to next node. But in case of dynamic node insertion, the only thing that would change is that a receiver node in the network can now no longer accept data from just one predefined transmitter node but it has to accept and process data from multiple transmitters and fulfill its responsibility of forwarding that data to the specific predefined node.

Comment: In this case of dynamic node insertion, there is a high probability that an intermediate receiver node will receive same data from multiple transmitters, so if a node has already forwarded that data (uniquely identified by packet number) then it should just discard it. ACK should always be sent to the transmitter to stop it from repeated transmission attempts flooding the wireless channel.

Comment: Thank you Sir  If i need your help then i will message you again